# How to disable automatically initialize local variable in Qt (gcc 64bit)

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

Local variables have undefined initial value.
But my code in Qt (gcc 64bit), all local variable (int, float,..) are automatically initialized to zero. I don't want this, because some bugs will not arise.
Ex : in a function : 
`int x;
double d; 
qDebug() << "x = " << x << "   d = " << d;`

+) Debug build: x = 0  d = 2.23959e-317

 All runs always show above result.

+) Release build x = 0 d = 0

My project is a normal Qt project (C++ 11 and I don't change any compiler flags). How can I turn off automatically  initialization local variable in Qt (gcc 64bit)

Comment: Are you sure, that you use local variables? Not global.

Comment: These variables are local in my test function.

Comment: Ok, what compiler flags are you using? Are debugging symbols turned on (they may be turned on in release build too)? Are there any optimization turned on? Why do you expect initialization with random values?

Comment: And... Why you don't want to turn on warnings on using uninitialized variables?

Comment: I use QtCreator, I don't change any compiler flags. Here is make file : CFLAGS        = -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -g -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE $(DEFINES). I want local variables must have garbage value if don't init. Compiler can make a warning, don't need automatically initialize value to zero.

Comment: What is "garbage"? Zero - is a value too. Compiler will not initialize local variables without direct instructions. You should review generated ASM code.

Answer (score 1):

How can you be sure your local vars are initialized? It is just undefined behaviour to use them without initialization, and only happens that they are zero, but you should not rely on this. You can try the following to convince yourself:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int* x = new int(42);
    delete x;
    // it may reuse the marked-as-available memory
    int* y = new int; 
    std::cout << *y; // often displays 42, so no zero-initialization
}
```

For example, this program sometimes reuses the already marked-as-deleted memory.
So, the output will often be `42`, since that was what happen to be located at that memory location (it happened to reuse the deleted memory of `*x`). It has nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: I only consider plain old datatype (int, float, double). I write a test function to print value of local variables without initialization. All integer local variables are automatically initialized to zero, float and double ~~ 0 ( 10^ - 317)